# Issue defining configuration defaults for Vuetify 3

Tags: vue.js, vuetifyjs3

**NOTE**: The question has been edited/updated as per @Moritz Ringler's answer.

In my Laravel 10, Vuetify 3 project, I am using many components that use several `<v-text-field>, <v-textarea>, <v-select>`, etc. I want to use the same settings for **density** and **variant** with all components, e.g.

```
<v-select
     density="compact"
     variant="outlined"
     v-model="lu_duration_id"
     :items="lu_duration"
     label="Duration"
></v-select>
```

I have tried to define these in `app.js`, as shown:

```
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'


// For Vuetify material icons
import { aliases, mdi } from 'vuetify/iconsets/mdi'
import 'vuetify/styles'
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
const icons = {
    defaultSet: 'mdi',
    aliases,
    sets: {
      mdi,
    }
  }

 // default options
 const defaults = {
    global: {
        variant: "outlined",
    },
    VSelect: {
        density: "compact",
    },
};


const vuetify = createVuetify({
    components,
    directives,
    icons,
    defaults,
    })
```

The **defaults** option, when included with `createVuetify` provides the desired affect, i.e. I see outlined effect on all components. However, the css (colours and look of all components gets messed up. For example, here is an image of a page before using `defaults` in `createVuetify`:

[image]

And, this is image of the page after including `defaults`:

[image]

The look of `<v-select>` changes significantly. Here is the image ofa page before using `defaults`

[image]

And this is an image after including `defaults`

[image]

One more thing I have observed that even before including `defaults`, look of my components is slightly different from those on the vuetify website. Notice that in the following image, the first `<v-text-field>` which has focus, has a thick border and the border has no radius. Even other components have a dark bottom border. (I am using  version 3.2.3 of Vuetify installed using npm)

[image]

Any tips to fix this issue is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [`defaults`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/global-configuration/#setup) property:

```
export default createVuetify({
  defaults: {
    global: {
      variant: 'outlined',
    },
    VSelect: {
      density: "compact",
    }
  }
}
```

The props in `global` will be set for all components that understand these props. Using the PascalCase name, you can set defaults for individual components.

Have a look at the snippet:

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;
const { createVuetify } = Vuetify
const vuetify = createVuetify({
  defaults:{
    global:{
      density: "compact",
      variant: 'outlined',
    }
  }
})
createApp({}).use(vuetify).mount('#app')
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main class="pa-4">
      <v-text-field label="label" :modelValue="value"/>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@3/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Mortiz Ringler: Using defaults, as you have suggested fixes the original issue. However, when I use 'defaults', it resets all css settings (to some values) that completely changes the look and spacing for everything (e.g. buttons, selects, etc.) I don't how the two issues are connected?

Comment: Do you mean that the `compact` density is applied to more elements than you like? You can specify defaults for individual components, I have added that to the answer. Otherwise, can you give me an exact example of what changes?

Comment: @Mortiz Ringler: I have updated the question to explain the issue I face after including `defaults` in createVuetify. Please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: As to the alert and the buttons (the first two images), yes, global means global. If you say you want the outlined variant for *all* components, alert and button get it too. If you want the variant only for some components, check the updated answer. Your select gets the outlined variant for the same reason. I don't know where the wireframe comes from, neither outlined nor compact even add borders to items. Please provide a sandbox if you want me to take a look at it. With the last image, I think the textbox has compact outlined active, where the others don't - did you override their variant?

Comment: @Mortiz Ringler: Thanks for the clarification. After defining defaults for the desired components (VTextarea, VTextField & VSelect), I am getting the desired effect, more or less. The only issue is that my controls don't have rounded corner. If I am unable to fix it, I will provide a sandbox and request you to have a look. Thanks once again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your can use this code for all components

```
const vuetify = createVuetify({
        theme: {
            defaultTheme: 'dark'
        },
        defaults: {
            VSelect: {
                density: "compact",
            },
            VTextField: {
                density: "compact",
            }
        }
    });
```

[image: Example]